# login form and session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, authentication

I have a login form with two boxes and button on buttonclick I validate user using sql database and store the id in session and set up FormsAuthentication for later use. on logout button I redirect them logout.aspx where i destroy the session and redirect to login page :

```
 Session.Abandon();
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

now after logout if i go back using browser back button, I still can see my previouse page but if I refresh I get `object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
Line 33:         {
Line 34:             string id = Session["ID"].ToString();
```

What is the best work around for this to send user back to login if this happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nota : i suggest you to use

```
if(Session["ID"] != null)
{

}
```

But also I suggest you to use this `configuration`

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
           defaultUrl="default.aspx" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Your logout link/button should point to a page containing this code, along with whatever else you want.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Put user code to initialize the page here
    Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

Nota :  sequence diagram

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if the `Session["ID"] != null`
Otherwise the user is not authenticated.

But if you use FormsAuthentication you can also use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`